# See all questions I have asked in all the Stack Exchange sites in one place

Tags: feature-request, questions, stack-exchange

A feature to display/list all the questions I have asked in every site on Stack Exchange (whether they are questions with upvotes or downvotes (positive points are negative points)).

Now only question with up votes (positive points) are listed in my profile.

I want to be able to see all the questions I have asked in every site in one place..

Comment: [This page](http://stackexchange.com/users/163214/kirk-hammett?tab=activity&filter=posts) lets you see all of your posts, but that includes your answers too (you have to explicitly click on the "posts" filter, linking to it doesn't work apparently).

Comment: @animuson I haven't seen any answers on that specific page. I think this should be close enough for Kirk Hammett :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information on your global Stack Exchange account is given in [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/163214/kirk-hammett); that includes:

- Your top questions and answers
- Your accounts on all the Stack Exchange sites
- Your reputation in the four sites where your reputation is higher
- Your activity, which includes:

  - The answers you accepted
  - The posts you made
  - Your badges
  - Your comments
  - Your revisions to posts
  - Your reviews
- Your favorites
- Your subscriptions