# Add filter page link on Stack Exchange profile page

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, filtering, network-profile

In a profile page of any Stack Exchange site if we filter any tab, it adds `&sort=XYZ`. E.g. [the activity tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056?tab=activity) on my meta profile page. In the activity tab if you click on particular filter option e.g. posts, then it will add `&sort=posts` as a parameter in the URL. So I can redirect anyone in [my profile -> activity -> posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056?tab=activity&sort=posts).

But in a *network* profile `?tab=xyz` parameter is available but `&sort=xyz` is not available. E.g. [my activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/163214/kirk-hammett?tab=activity) on my network profile. Here clicking on *posts* filter will filter by posts but it won't add `&sort=posts` parameter. Also a link with that parameter won't redirect us to the filtered page. E.g. I can not link like this: [my network profile -> activity -> posts](https://stackexchange.com/users/1452838/hims056?tab=activity&sort=posts).

This is already noted by [@animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197095/see-all-questions-i-have-asked-in-all-the-stack-exchange-sites-in-one-place#comment623251_197095). So it is request to add filter page link on network profile page too.

Comment: You can see the raw data: http://stackexchange.com/users/activity/163214?page=1&filter=posts the network profile is using AJAX to parse it nicely.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nice but how did you find that link?

Comment: This is the URL of the "sub filters" (accepts, posts, badges etc) :)